# reviews of a submitted paper after payment

Tags: peer-review

I have submitted an article to a CS conference that its proceedings are indexed by Springer in its series entitled Advances in Intelligent Systems and Computing, the link is:
https://www.springer.com/series/11156

The problem is that I have gotten an acceptance letter from this conference, but they tell me that for getting the reviews I should pay the registration fee first. One colleague told me that the organizers from this conference usually they do that. So, I would like to know if this kind of behavior is normal in some conferences, because when I have submitted to other venues the policy was that they send an acceptance or rejection letter, but with the comments made by the reviewers. By the way the conference has been indexed by Scopus in the last two years and it does not appear in the list of predatory journals.

Any help would be useful.

Thanks

Comment: Mostly, getting a paper accepted at a CS conference implies that at least one author will actually attend. I'm surprised they are playing hard-ball with the reviews, but your attendance (and payment of necessary fees) is expected.